# Is there a way to stock automatically jmeter results in nexus repository?

Tags: jmeter, nexus

I am new to jmeter and i am trying to find a way to save all jmeter results in nexus repository so i can be able to compare previous results to the current results.
Does anyone have an idea ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into [How can I programmatically upload files into Nexus 3?](https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/115006744008-How-can-I-programmatically-upload-files-into-Nexus-3-) article it's a matter of a single simple [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)

1. Configure JMeter to flush the results into the .jtl file as soon as they're available by adding the next line to *user.properties* file

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush=true
   ```
2. Add [tearDown Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) to your Test Plan
3. Add [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler to the tearDown Thread Group and configure it to upload the .jtl results file to Nexus repository:

   [image]
4. You might also need to add [HTTP Authorization Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-http-basic-authentication-jmeter/) in order to provide Nexus credentials

---

You can also use [Merge Results](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/MergeResults/) JMeter Plugin which has possibility to compare up to 4 .jtl results files.